# How to compute Shannon entropy of Information from a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, entropy

I have a dataframe `df` that contains the information of transactions from a individual `Name_Give` to another `Name_Receive` like the following:

```
df
    Name_Give    Name_Receive   Amount
0    John           Tom          300
1    Eva            Tom          700
2    Sarah          Tom          100
3    John           Tom          200
4    Tom            Eva          700
5    John           Eva          300
6    Carl           Eva          250
```

for each `Name_Receive` `j` I would like to compute the Shannon Entropy as `S_j = -sum_i p_i \log p_i` where `p_i` is the amount divided by the sum of the amount for the user `j`

```
S_Tom = - (300/1300 * np.log(300/1300) + 700/1300 * np.log(700/1300) + 100/1300 * np.log(100/1300) + 200/1300 * np.log(200/1300))

S_Eva = - (700/1250 * np.log(700/1250) + 300/1250 * np.log(300/1250) + 250/1250 * np.log(250/1250)

S_Tom = 1.157
S_Eva = 0.99
```

I would like to have dataframe `df1` like the following

```
df1
     Name     Entropy
0    Tom      1.157
1    Eva      0.99
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`transfrom`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) to get total sum of each group and then divide the `Amount` column values with each group sum and compute the values :

```
g_sum = df.groupby('Name_Receive')['Amount'].transform('sum')
values = df['Amount']/g_sum
df['Entropy'] = -(values*np.log(values))

df1 = df.groupby('Name_Receive',as_index=False,sort=False)['Entropy'].sum()

print(df1)
  Name_Receive   Entropy
0          Tom  1.156988
1          Eva  0.989094
```

If the values contain 0's then use at the end after groupby:

```
df1['Entropy'] = df1['Entropy'].fillna(0)
```

Since `0*np.log(0)` gives `nan` to make it `0` use `fillna`.

Comment: I think it's a good solution, but only assuming you have no 0 values in the 'Amount' column.
`>>> np.log([1, np.e, np.e**2, 0])` will result in : `array([  0.,   1.,   2., -Inf])`
While calculating Entropy zero values should be skipped (or summed as zeros)

Comment: @Oleg When you multiply `0*np.log(0)` you get `nan`, not `Inf`. This can be filled using `fillna(0)` easily. While writing the answer I considered only the sample data and not any other limitations like this.

Comment: For the sample data it will work,
but personally I came to it looking for a solution for my case.
Perhaps you should consider adding an option for 0 values to cover all the cases.
Your suggestion should work, I think another way to do it will be using 
`import scipy.stats as st`
`df['Entropy'] = st.entropy(values)`

Comment: @Oleg I tested `st.entropy` even this gives `nan`  and Updated the answer for `0` case.

Answer (score 3):

You could also apply the entropy function of scipy

```
from scipy.stats import entropy
E = df.groupby('Name_Receive')['Amount'].apply(lambda x : entropy(x.value_counts(), base=2)).reset_index()
```